# how to implement the pagination for tree2 using jsf?

Tags: java, jsf-1.2, tomahawk

Hi i am working on tree2 implemetation using jsf 1.2 . I have more than 100 rows and i have to show only 10 rows in a page. can anyone let me know how to implement the pagination for tree2?